# Uipath overdrives Excel file Locale configuration

Tags: excel, uipath, regional-settings

I have to process some excel files that comes with an specific Numeric format that is es-CL
that has dots as a thousand separator and comas as decimal separator.

Thousand separator = 100.000.000

Decimal= 1.000.000,1213

When i use any of the excel activities the numbers inside the excel change their format and leaves them like this

Before: 13.640

After:13,64

the thousand separator becomes a coma and the 0 is erased.
I already tried the “Preserve Format” option, replacing the dots with a "" and i get the same result.
Is there a way to change the locale of the excel activities, if it not, what are my options?

Comment: what activities do you use? are these activities overwritting your Excel file or your DataTable looks like this?

Comment: @IlyaKochetov, The Data changes at the moment Uipath touches the excel with either the excel scope activities or the workbook activities, i solved using python to do all the work related to excel and running the script using Uipath activities

Comment: Number is just a number. If you see in excel number as 10.000,56, that is formatting, and has nothing to do with actual value. This formatting is decided by system settings, different per computer. Once you open the file, you see it in your system formatting. Once you send it back, on that computer they gonna see it in their format. Only exception is if you store number as string.